# Rename a file/ remove numbers from a file name in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, file, rename

My code runs well when I didn't ask to rename the file, just to print all file names without number, but when I did it and checked file instead of running it, it just doesn't work.

**here's my code:**

```
import os
import re
def rename_file():

file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Zoe.Zhao\Desktop\prank")

saved_path = os.getcwd()

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Zoe.Zhao\Desktop\prank")

print (saved_path)

for file_name in file_list:

file_name = re.sub('[0-9]','',file_name)

print(file_name)

rename_file()
```

Here are some sreenshots:

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

Comment: Your indentation is off. That's why you get only the name of the last item in your list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new list: see below:

```
import os
import re
def rename_file():

    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\afareh\Dropbox\PROGRAMMING\test\prank\prank")
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(r"C:\Users\afareh\Dropbox\PROGRAMMING\test\prank\prank")


    new_file_list=[]    # create an empty list for storing the names of the renamed files. 
    for file_name in file_list:

        file_name=re.sub('[0-9]','',file_name)
        new_file_list.append(file_name)

    print (new_file_list)   

rename_file()
```